# sort Postgresql table contents

Tags: php, postgresql

I want to sort the contents of my Postgresql table on the basis of numbers(a column name) in descending order.
I am using -

```
$query = pg_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY numbers DESC");
```

There is no error when I execute this query but when I go to my table in postgresql, it is unsorted. I think I am missing something.

Any help?

Comment: You only sort the result of the SQL query not in the database it self

Comment: how to sort  the database table?

Comment: Why would you want to sort the table itself?? It doesn't make any sense at all

Comment: So that In my table the name should be in the order from highest to lowest numbers.

Comment: Why do you want to store the data in a specific order in the table? There is usually no good reason to do that. Order them upon retrieval. For fast searching and ordering, use an index.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you want the table itself to be sorted, since the `ORDER BY` clause in the `SELECT` statement only sorts the output of the statement.

**EDIT**

If you want to sort the contents of the table, you need to `CLUSTER` it.

The cluster statement is defined at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-cluster.html (for version 9.1).

`CLUSTER [VERBOSE] table_name [ USING index_name ]`

Altough PostgreSQL does not really support what you are asking since CLUSTERing is a one-time operation.
As per the documentation:

> When a table is clustered, it is physically reordered based on the index information. **Clustering is a one-time operation: when the table is subsequently updated, the changes are not clustered.** That is, no attempt is made to store new or updated rows according to their index order. (If one wishes, one can periodically recluster by issuing the command again. Also, setting the table's FILLFACTOR storage parameter to less than 100% can aid in preserving cluster ordering during updates, since updated rows are kept on the same page if enough space is available there.)

Comment: yes I want the table itself to be sorted on the basis of numbers(an integer type column).

Comment: Please do not post comments as answers

Comment: the thing is when I use "SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY numbers DESC in postgresql," it sorts table in descending order on the basis of numbers. But when I execute this command in php script, no sorting occurs in table.

Comment: I have updated my answer, I believe it is both an explanation of the behaviour as a solution to the question.